# How to Capture a screenshot and share using flutter

Tags: flutter, flame

Is it possible to take a screenshot of the screen using [flame](https://pub.dev/packages/flame) and flutter? So when the user clicks a button, it will share the screenshot with anyone he chooses to share it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are specifically using `flame`, you are in luck! Flame renders your game on the canvas. Your game `render` method takes a canvas and draws a frame of your game.

Normally the canvas provided is the device screen, but can easily call the render method yourself with a different canvas, say, an image.

```dart
    final PictureRecorder recorder = PictureRecorder();
    final Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, game.size.width, game.size.height);
    final Canvas c = Canvas(recorder, rect);

    game.render(c);

    final image = await recorder.endRecording().toImage(game.size.width, game.size.height);
```

Then you can save that image on, let's say, a file, or in memory.

Now note that this will render only your game, and will render the exact frame you are in when you call this. But I assume that is what you want since you specifically tagged this question with `flame`. There might be better ways of screenshooting with Flutter in general, but using flame, this is the best way.